# Prophet trend model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, generalized-additive-model, prophet

Can someone help me understand how Prophet automatically detects the change points in its piecewise linear trend model?

Please check page 10 of Prophet paper (Forecasting at Scale: https://peerj.com/preprints/3190.pdf)

Thank you so much

Comment: its perhaps more complicated than it needs to be but essentially its fitting a series of 'hockey stick' functions with l1 (lasso) regularisation so it will drop out (set coefficient to zero) minor changes.

Comment: and what's the idea behind choosing L1 and not L2?

Comment: L1 drops out whole changepoints, whereas L2 will set the coefficient to small values.

Answer (score 3):

With default options, Prophet detects changepoints by first specifying 25 potential changepoints at which the rate/slope of the trend is allowed to change. They are uniformly placed in the first 80% of the time series. It then puts a sparse prior on the magnitudes of the rate changes, so most of them get shrunk to zero. You can also manually specify the locations of potential changepoints. Slope changes will then be allowed only at these points, with the same sparse regularization as before.

This info can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/trend_changepoints.html), with some guidance on how to set these three parameters.